# Encerrando duas Thread com ProgressBar em C#

Tags: c#, thread, progress-bar

Estou fazendo um `ProgressBar` de conversões de arquivos, a cada arquivo convertido, é atualizada a `ProgressBar` com uma porcentagem do total de arquivos a serem convertidos.

Li em um Tutorial como fazer a `ProgressBar`, trabalhar com `Threads` com ela e eis o meu problema:

Ao cancelar o form da `ProgressBar` (tenho um botão para isso) o `form` é de fato encerrado, mas a Conversão continua rodando, (notei isso porquê essas conversões vão para uma pasta especifica que continua recebendo arquivos novos).

Preciso saber Como interromper as duas `Threads` ao mesmo tempo:

**Código**

```
private void bgwProgresso_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ListaCandidatos.Count; i++)
    {
        Arquivo arq = new Arquivo();
        arq.Linhas = Importadora.LerArquivo(ListaCandidatos[i]);
        arq.SetNome(arq.Linhas);
        arq.Endereco = ListaCandidatos[i];
        arq.SemanaEntrega = arq.GetSemanaEntrega(ListaCandidatos[i]);
        arq.Validacao = true;
        this.EnderecosConvertidos.Add(conv.ProcessarOC(arq));
        int percent = (int)(((double)(i + 1) / (double)(ListaCandidatos.Count - 1)) * 100);
        this.bgwProgresso.ReportProgress(percent);
        pbProgresso.CreateGraphics().DrawString(percent.ToString() + "%", new Font("Arial", (float)8.25, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new PointF(pbProgresso.Width / 2 - 10, pbProgresso.Height / 2 - 7));

    }
    if (bgwProgresso.CancellationPending)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        return;
    }
    bgwProgresso.ReportProgress(100);

}

private void bgwProgresso_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
    this.Close();
}

private void btnCancelar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (bgwProgresso.IsBusy)
    {
        bgwProgresso.CancelAsync();
    }
    lblStatus.Text = "Cancelado";
    this.Close();
}

private void bgwProgresso_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    pbProgresso.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

Achei que poderia ser o `if` ao final do Loop e inclui ele no código, mas também não funcionou e ainda me arremesou uma **Exception** no `ProgressChanged`

**Código**

```
private void bgwProgresso_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
for (int i = 0; i < ListaCandidatos.Count; i++)
{
    Arquivo arq = new Arquivo();
    arq.Linhas = Importadora.LerArquivo(ListaCandidatos[i]);
    arq.SetNome(arq.Linhas);
    arq.Endereco = ListaCandidatos[i];
    arq.SemanaEntrega = arq.GetSemanaEntrega(ListaCandidatos[i]);
    arq.Validacao = true;
    this.EnderecosConvertidos.Add(conv.ProcessarOC(arq));
    int percent = (int)(((double)(i + 1) / (double)(ListaCandidatos.Count - 1)) * 100);
    this.bgwProgresso.ReportProgress(percent);
    pbProgresso.CreateGraphics().DrawString(percent.ToString() + "%", new Font("Arial", (float)8.25, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new PointF(pbProgresso.Width / 2 - 10, pbProgresso.Height / 2 - 7));
    this.pbProgresso.BeginInvoke(
        new Action(() =>
        {
            if (bgwProgresso.CancellationPending)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                return;
            }
        }
        ));
}
bgwProgresso.ReportProgress(100);    
}

private void bgwProgresso_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
    this.Close();
}

private void btnCancelar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (bgwProgresso.IsBusy)
    {
        bgwProgresso.CancelAsync();
    }
    lblStatus.Text = "Cancelado";
    this.Close();
}

private void bgwProgresso_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    pbProgresso.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

Me foi arremessada essa **Exceção**:

**Erro**

> Operação entre threads inválida: controle 'pbProgresso' acessado de um
>   thread que não é aquele no qual foi criado

Atualização:

Ao contrario do que me sugeriram, eu preciso encerrar ambas as Threads, não só a visualização da ProgressBar.

Comment: Você está usando BackgroundWorker certo? Você configurou o BackgroundWorker para suportar cancelamento, interrompendo o processo/thread? Exemplo: ** bgw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true; ** Faça um teste para ver se resolve

Comment: Sim sim @Renan, estava configurado anteriormente como true , eu usava uma barra de progresso sem step, e la funcionava isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foi necessário implementar algumas ações quanto ao botão de cancelamento, segue código revisado e funcional:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < ListaCandidatos.Count; i++)
        {
            Arquivo arq = new Arquivo();
            arq.Linhas = Importadora.LerArquivo(ListaCandidatos[i]);
            arq.SetNome(arq.Linhas);
            arq.Endereco = ListaCandidatos[i];
            arq.SemanaEntrega = arq.GetSemanaEntrega(ListaCandidatos[i]);
            arq.Validacao = true;
            if (bgwProgresso.CancellationPending)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                bgwProgresso.ReportProgress(0);
                return;
            }
            this.EnderecosConvertidos.Add(conv.ProcessarOC(arq));
            lblStatus.BeginInvoke(
                new Action(() =>
            {
                lblStatus.Text = string.Format("Convertendo {0} de {1}...", i, ListaCandidatos.Count);
            }
                ));
            int percent = (int)(((double)(i + 1) / (double)(ListaCandidatos.Count)) * 100);
            this.bgwProgresso.ReportProgress(percent);
        }
        bgwProgresso.ReportProgress(100);
    }

    //o que fazer no fim.
    private void bgwProgresso_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
            this.Close();
        } else if(e.Error != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Erro desconhecido");
            this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }

    private void btnCancelar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (bgwProgresso.IsBusy)
        {
            bgwProgresso.CancelAsync();
        }
        lblStatus.Text = "Cancelando...";
    }

    private void bgwProgresso_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ProgressPercentage >= 100)
        {
            bgwProgresso.Dispose();
            this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            pbProgresso.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            pbProgresso.CreateGraphics().DrawString(e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%", new Font("Arial", (float)8.25, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new PointF(pbProgresso.Width / 2 - 10, pbProgresso.Height / 2 - 7));
        }
    }
```